# How to send and get php variable to the next page?

Tags: php, html, oracle-call-interface

I have three pages which is first page is retrieve data from database. Second or edit page is  to edit data that I choose when I click the check box and pass value via button edit. Last or delete page is to delete data that also choose from check box and pass value via delete button.

Below is my code..

***first page***

```
    <?php

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM STAFF ORDER BY STAFF_NAME ASC';
        $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
        oci_execute($stmt);             

    ?> 
    <table width="900" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <th>Staff ID</th>
        <th>Staff  Name</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>

      <?php 
            $a = 1;
            while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
      ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['STAFF_ID']  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['STAFF_NAME']  ?></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="chk'<?php echo $a ?>' " value="<?php echo $row['STAFF_ID'];?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
                $a = $a + '1';
            }
            oci_free_statement($stmt);
            oci_close($conn);
    ?>

    </table>
    <button>Edit</button>
    <button>Delete</button>
```

***second / edit page***

```
    <?php
        $sql = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT COUNT(STAFF_ID) AS COUNT_ROW FROM STAFF");
        oci_execute($sql);
        $row = oci_fetch_array($sql);
        $a =  $row["COUNT_ROW"];

        for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
          {
            if(isset($_POST["chk".$i]) )
              {
                $stmt = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM STAFF WHERE STAFF_ID = :staff_id ");
                oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':vendor_id',$vendor_id1,10);
                $vendor_id1 = $_POST["chk".$i];
                $objExecute = oci_execute($stmt);
                $row = oci_fetch_array($stmt);
              }
             else{
                   echo "No Data Selected";
                 }
          }
    ?>

<input type="text" placeholder="Staff ID" name="staff_id" value="<?php echo $row['STAFF_ID'];?>">
<input type="text" placeholder="Staff Name" name="staff_name" value="<?php echo $row['STAFF_NAME'];?>">
```

Comment: Use GET, POST or Session ? What exactly is the question ?

Comment: @fakhrul Are you familiar with **MVC**? For editing something you will need a _form_. If you want to go to the edit page, you could use a link that contains the data's **id** as a **GET** parameter. Then before you load the content on the edit page just grab the data from the database where the `id == $_GET['id']`.

Comment: @Mihailo can you show an example?

Comment: @fakhrul It would be very impractical for me to show you here. You can look up some videos or articles about this. You need to read up on **GET**, **POST**, **SESSION** in php. It's really important you understand these, before moving on. + Robert has you covered with the premise of it all.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways of doing it.

1. You can use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) with $_SESSION or your own session mechanism
2. You can use database or any storage save it on one page and retrieve on the other
3. You can pass variable via http request like [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)/[POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and get it via $_POST or $_GET. Other http methods are possible to use as well.
4. You can use [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) with $_COOKIE

## Examples:

### Session:

Session is used when you want to pass variables data across subsequent accesses. For example you logged the user and you want to get his login only once from db and keep it in session so on any page you can access it.

**page_1.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESION['variable'] = 'value';
```

**page_2.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['variable'];
```

### Database:

Is used when the information you want to keep should be held for longer time but not always. It mostly depends on the db kind. Sometimes the session mechanisms uses databases. It is pretty common that redis is used for session storage.

**page_1.php**

```
 $db->query("INSERT INTO storage_table(name,value) VALUES('variable', 'value')");
```

**page_2.php**

```
 var_dump($db->query("SELECT value FROM storage_table WHERE name='variable'")->fetch());
```

### HTTP method GET

Common use of get is when you want to pass variables that change the output. For example you have results that needs to be paginated so the urls looks like data.php?page=2 so in PHP you will get it with $_GET['page'];

**page_1.php**

```
 header('Location: page_2.php?variable=value');
```

**page_2.php**

```
 echo $_GET['variable'];
```

### Cookies

Cookies are used if you want to preserve some information even after user closed a browser.They are used for storing data in the remote browser and thus tracking or identifying return users.

**page_1.php**

```
<?php
setcookie("variable","value");
```

**page_2.php**

```
<?php
echo $_COOKIE["variable"];
```

So as you see there are plenty of methods to pass variables to another page. I've put only some examples but there are more advanced ones with curl, redis, HTTP push etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously do it in many ways, but because you already have build a structure for the `$_POST` method, I think that is the way to go.

So I think you want to edit the rows where the checkbox is checked right? The values you want to 'send' to the next page are the 'chk[ANYNUMBER]' checkboxes.

To do that you need to wrap the table and the buttons in the first page into a `<form>`. Make sure the `<form>` uses the POST method and the edit page as the action, so `<form method="POST" action="page2.php">` Second make sure the edit `button` becomes a `submit` so the form is submitted when clicked on it.

Now you can get the values in the second page with `$_POST[ANYINPUTNAME]` so for `example $_POST["chk1"]`

**EDIT**

So is how your first page should look like this (note the `input` and the `form` tags AND change `page2.php` into your page name):

```
       ...
      <form method="post" action="page2.php">
        <table width="900" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <th>Staff ID</th>
            <th>Staff  Name</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>

          <?php $a = 1; while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['STAFF_ID']  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['STAFF_NAME']  ?></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="chk'<?php echo $a ?>' " value="<?php echo $row['STAFF_ID'];?>"></td>
          </tr>
          <?php $a = $a + '1'; } oci_free_statement($stmt); oci_close($conn); ?>

        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="edit_button" value="Edit">
        <input type="submit" name="delete_button" value="Delete">
      </form>
```

Comment: If I have another button which is delete `button` and what should I do in `form` ?